# Can I use SQL CASE statement inside GoogleSheets QUERY?

Tags: sql, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, nested-if

How can I (or is it possible?) use something like `CASE` statement in `T-SQL` inside `QUERY` in Google spreadsheet?

I want to do something like this:

`=QUERY(A6:AI,"select A,(CASE WHEN D>2.5 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END),E,C,J")`

I want basically a custom column with Yes/No values based on other column. Is it possible?

EDIT: To better explain, I have data in table `Existing table` and I would like to transform it to the `Transformed table` using `QUERY` statement:

[image]

So I need something to say: *if column D is empty, print No, otherwise print Yes*. This has to be in the `QUERY` because it's not the last column, there will be more data after column `Finished`. So I have this:

`=QUERY(A4:D,"Select A, B, (CASE WHEN D='' THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END)")` - But that doesn't work

Thank you for help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` & `THEN` are not supported in google's query language

try:

```
=INDEX({A6:A, IF(D6:D>2.5, "yes", "no"), E6:E, C6:C, J6:J})
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how can I use it in the QUERY though. Can please help me out?

Comment: @AdamWojnar can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Comment: Please take a look at my edited question

Comment: The spreadsheet is only like 15% complete, so It's hard for me to show you the whole picture. But it's actually a simple transformation. Basically some columns will be copy&pasted as they are, some will be modified to show "Yes/No" information. If it's possible without `QUERY` then I'm all for it. Probably when I wrote *"This has to be in the QUERY"* - was a little bit too strong. I thought I don't have other options

Comment: @AdamWojnar in that case all you need is included in provided answer. if range does not change use the range itself (either 1 column A6:A or multiple columns A6:C) and if it changes to yes/no use IF statement to change it as you wish. other than that... all is comma-separated inside {} array brackets and wrapped into INDEX or ARRAYFORMULA